# VBA adodb recordset fieldname contain hash sign instead of dot

Tags: vba, adodb, recordset

I wrote the excel macro which imports CSV file into internal custom dataset for future use in other functions. I am using Schema.ini file to configure fields types for each column in the CSV file. I reached an issue for which I cannot find resolution on the web.
The CSV files are being read correctly, but once in the original CSV column header contains a dot sign "." recordset reads it as a hash sign "#". Is there any settings which I should take care about in order to get macro working well for me?

```
Dim sqlConnection As ADODB.Connection
Set sqlConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Dim sqlRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Set sqlRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & sCSVFolderPath & ";" & _
      "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited(,)"""

sqlRecordset.Open "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & sCSVFileName & "]", _
          sqlConnection, sqlOpenStatic, sqlLockOptimistic, adCmdText
```

Again - any time column header contains dot sign (i.e 'Header.1') it is being read with hash sign ('Header#1').

Comment: Try explicitly referenceig columns in `SELECT` instead of asterisk, `*`, and escape all column names with back ticks or square brackets.

Comment: Thank You for the answer. May I ask You to be more specific? can You write an example? My VBA skills are still at learning path :).

Comment: This is what I meant in simply adjusting your SQL call: `sqlRecordset.Open "SELECT [Header.1], [Header.2], [Header.3] FROM " & "[" & sCSVFileName & "]"`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me as if adodb replaces separator characters (like dots) with hash characters. If you're sure your field names dont contain hashes, you can change them back to dots, but I would'nt call that a solution....

No clue if other chars are also replaced by adobd either.